# How to remove initial empty value for a dropdown attribute in Magento?

Tags: magento, drop-down-menu, attributes, default

I'm using Magento version 1.5.1.0.  I added an attribute with the following options selected in the Properties tab:

```
Catalog input type for store owner: dropdown
Unique value: no
Values required: no
```

I then went to the Manage Label/Options tab and added 3 different options, selecting the first option as a default.  I added it to an attribute set, and when I go to enter a product, I see the dropdown, but with an empty option value prepended to it:

```html
<select>
    <option selected="selected"></option>
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
    <option>Option 3</option>
</select>
```

When I save the product, the empty option still remains selected.  How do I remove that empty option and make Option 1 the default for all of my existing products without resorting to using JS or editing any files whatsoever?

Comment: It would be helpful to everyone if you could explain why you downvoted.

Comment: Hi, I know it's an old question but in Magento 1.9 still happening. The problem is not painting the html its because the array with options have an empty value. Like this: array(2) { [0]=> array(2) { ["label"]=> string(0) "" ["value"]=> string(0) "" } [1]=> array(2) { ["value"]=> string(1) "8" ["label"]=> string(15) "blablablabla" } }   In my case it happens with product attributes in the frontend.

Answer (score 3):

I think this can help.

When you call getAllOptions you need to pass false.

->getAllOptions(false)

[Magento attribute dropdown with first empty value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31534910/magento-attribute-dropdown-with-first-empty-value/31535139#31535139)

Comment: Hey your suggestion is worked for me i have upvoted as well. but may i know what is the meaning of FALSE ? just for my knowledge. If i pass false then exactly what happen ? Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="history[status]" class="select" id="history_status">
     <option value="pending" selected="selected">Pending</option>
     <option value="canceled">Canceled</option>
     <option value="processing">Processing</option>
</select>
```

Try using the SELECT tag rather than option for this block. Here above I have an example taken from a Magento store. Your:

```
<option selected="selected></option>
```

Is exactly that. An option, rather than defining a select box.

Comment: I edited my question for more clarity.  The problem is I never added an empty value to the option list.  I want to do this all in the backend and without any markup or scripting if possible.  Right now, I'm using JS because time isn't on my side, but if anybody knows what I'm missing it would help a lot.

Comment: I missed your comment it seems, I'll look it over in the morning when I'm better rested.